# Go: running a TCP server on two different ports at the same time?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a multi-protocol server using Go. One server is an HTTP server, listening on 80. Another, is a custom-made protocol (over TCP) running on port 8088. Is this possible with Go?

Comment: Of course it is possible. You duplicate the lines launching one server and you change the port. But did you at least research how a http server is made in Go ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
func serveHTTP() { http.ListenAndServe(...) }
func serveCustom() { net.Listen("tcp", ...) }

go serveHTTP()
go serveCustom()
```